# OpenCL allcoation flag CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR usage not referencing my pointer

Tags: opencl, gpu, intel

I was trying to use the flag `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` with the OpenCL function `clCreateBuffer()` in order to avoid multiple memory allocation. After a little research (reverse engineering), I found that the framework calls the operating system allocation function no matter what flag I use.

Maybe my concept is wrong? But from documentation it's supposed to use DMA to access the host memory instead of allocating new memory.

I am using opencl 1.2 on an Intel device (HD5500)

Comment: Which implementation? Beignet?

Comment: No, i am using opencl implementation on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Intel GPUs ensure the allocated host pointer is page aligned and page length*.  In fact I think the buffer size can actually be an even number of cache lines, but I always round up.

Use something like:

```
void *host_ptr = _aligned_malloc(align_to(size,4096),4096));
```

[Here's a good article for this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-the-most-from-opencl-12-how-to-increase-performance-by-minimizing-buffer-copies-on-intel-processor-graphics):
In the "Key Takeaways".

> If you already have the data and want to load the data into an OpenCL
>   buffer object, then use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` with a buffer allocated at
>   a 4096 byte boundary (aligned to a page and cache line boundary) and a
>   total size that is a multiple of 64 bytes (cache line size).

You can also use `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR` and let the driver handle the allocation.  But to get at the pointer you'll have to map and unmap it (but at no copy cost).

Comment: Does that mean, implementation fixes the error that developer has forgotten to make it multiple of 64? Can we trust other corporations like AMD, NVIDIA, ..?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure. Even with `ALLOC_HOST_POINTER` I'd ensure to round the length up to a 64-byte multiple. One could test this presumably.

Comment: Regarding AMD and NV, I can't speak for their implementations.